# XMLHttpRequest error. when call api in flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, flutter-web

i am using http: ^0.12.2 to call api in flutter web project ,  and  i have this error :XMLHttpRequest , Although when run this project at ios simulator , it work fine .
please help .

Comment: Can you provide more details which api, code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

i already get solution for this problem , by enable cors in back-end .
thanks.

Comment: How did you enable that ??????????